# Is it OK to refresh the site every 5 minutes if you have google AdSense on your website

Tags: adsense

I heard it is not smart to use techniques to refresh just ads on the website with [Google AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/1920512?hl=en). This is so OK.

But is it possible to refresh the page every 5 minutes when site uses Google AdSense .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en (Auto-refreshing ads) section - it's not allowed to refresh the whole page without user requesting refresh.